# Работа массива указателей в Си

Tags: c, массивы, указатели

Здравствуйте. Читаю K&R, добрался до массива указателей в частности до программы которая сортирует строки лексикографически. Но так как логика указателей мне еще не до конца понятно я попутался модифицировать программу таким образом, чтобы после завершения ввода в консоли, она просто записала массив указателей. Вот, что получилось

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#define MAXLINES 5000 /* максимальное число строк */
#define MAXLEN 1000000

char *lineptr[MAXLINES]; // Собственно массив указателей
char file[MAXLEN]; // Это массив, в котором полностью записан ручной ввод
char linetest[MAXLEN]; // Массив в который будет записываться по одной строке
char *a = file;

int get_line(char *to, char *from);
void get_file(char *s);

int main()
{
    int len;
    int nlines = 0; /* количество прочитанных строк */
    get_file (a);
    while (*a != '\0')
    {
        len = get_line (linetest, a);
        char *p;
        p = linetest;
        lineptr[nlines++] = p;
        printf ("%s s nomerom %d\n", lineptr[3], nlines);
        a = a + len; 
    }

}

// Читаем весь ввод в массив

void get_file(char *s)
{
    int c;
    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF)
        {
            *s = c;
            s++;
        }
    *s = '\0';
}

// Получаем строку из массива

int get_line(char *to, char *from)
{
    int len = 0;
    while (*from != '\n' && *from != '\0')
    {
        *to++ = *from++;
        len++;
    }
    if (*from == '\0' || *from == '\n')
    {
        *to = '\0';
        len++;
    }
    return len;
}
```

Вот результат работы программы. После ввода в консоль стихотворения

```
The shepherds went their hasty way,
And found the lowly stable-shed
Where the Virgin-Mother lay:
And now they checked their eager tread,
For to the Babe, that at her bosom clung,
A Mother's song the Virgin-Mother sung.
```

Мне выдает следующий результат

```
(null) s nomerom 1
(null) s nomerom 2
(null) s nomerom 3
And now they checked their eager tread, s nomerom 4
For to the Babe, that at her bosom clung, s nomerom 5
A Mother's song the Virgin-Mother sung. s nomerom 6
```

К первым трем строкам вопросов нет. Но почему в дальнейшем начинает перезаписываться lineptr[3]? Ведь в моем случае результат должен выглядеть так

```
(null) s nomerom 1
(null) s nomerom 2
(null) s nomerom 3
And now they checked their eager tread, s nomerom 4
And now they checked their eager tread, s nomerom 5
And now they checked their eager tread, s nomerom 6
```

Ткните меня пожалуйста в то место, где я ошибаюсь

Answer (score 2):

Одна ошибка спряталась здесь

```
// получили строку, все ок
len = get_line (linetest, a);
char *p;
// в p теперь просто указатель
// содержимое буфера не скопировано, оно существует в одной копии
p = linetest;
// тут ещё раз перенесли указатель на изначальный буфер
lineptr[nlines++] = p;
```

И когда проходит вторая итеррация цикла, то буфер `linetest` перетирается новой строкой. Но на него также указывает и `lineptr[...]`. В результате в конце оказывается, что lineptr хранит несколько одинаковых указателей.

Краткий фикс - использоваться strdup, которая делает выделение памяти и копирование туда строки.

```
lineptr[nlines++] = strdup(p);
```

Второе - это освобождение памяти. Так как у Вас вся память выделялась статически, то и проблем не было. Но strdup выделяет динамически и нужно освобождать через free.

Answer (score 0):

@KoVadim, спасибо. До динамического выделения памяти я не добрался еще, но ваш ответ навел меня на ошибку.

Если кому-то вдруг интересно, то вот правильный код

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define MAXLINES 5000 /* максимальное число строк */
#define MAXLEN 1000000

char *lineptr[MAXLINES];
char file[MAXLEN];
char linetest[MAXLEN];
char *a = file;
char p[MAXLINES];
char *p1 = p;

int get_line(char *to, char *from);
void str_cpy(char *s, char *t);
void get_file(char *s);


int main()
{
    int len;
    int nlines = 0; /* количество прочитанных строк */
    get_file (a);

    while (*a != '\0')
    {
        char line[MAXLINES];
        len = get_line (line, a);
        str_cpy(p1, line);
        lineptr[nlines++] = p1;
        printf ("%s s nomerom %d\n", lineptr[3], nlines);
        a = a + len; 
        p1 = p1 + len;
    }

}

// Читаем весь ввод в массив

void get_file(char *s)
{
    int c;
    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF)
        {
            *s = c;
            s++;
        }
    *s = '\0';
}

// Получаем строку из массива

int get_line(char *to, char *from)
{
    int len = 0;
    while (*from != '\n' && *from != '\0')
    {
        *to++ = *from++;
        len++;
    }
    if (*from == '\0' || *from == '\n')
    {
        *to = '\0';
        len++;
    }
    return len;
}

// Копирование

void str_cpy(char *to, char *from)
{
    while (*from != '\0')
       {
           *to = *from;
           to++;
           from++;
       }
    *to = '\0';
}
```

Ввод:

```
The shepherds went their hasty way,
And found the lowly stable-shed
Where the Virgin-Mother lay:
And now they checked their eager tread,
For to the Babe, that at her bosom clung,
A Mother's song the Virgin-Mother sung.
```

Результат:

```
//(null) s nomerom 1
//(null) s nomerom 2
//(null) s nomerom 3
//And now they checked their eager tread, s nomerom 4
//And now they checked their eager tread, s nomerom 5
//And now they checked their eager tread, s nomerom 6
```